# EF Core does not return record by id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app with a repository layer. I wanted to test some stuff, and wrote this in the controller:

```
[HttpGet("testPublish")]
public IActionResult TestPublish()
{
    Guid eventId = Guid.Parse("5522936D-70B1-4B75-3B83-08D97DC382B7");
    _service.FinishEvent(eventId);
    return Ok();
}
```

The database has a record with this event id. Inside `FinishEvent` method there is a call to repository method to get the event, here it is:

```
public Event GetEventForFinishNotification(Guid eventId)
{
    return _dbContext.Events
                     .Include(a => a.Lots)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Action)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.ActionStatus)
                     .Include(a => a.Lots)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Action)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.ActionResponses)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.ActionResponseItems)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Items)
                     .Include(a => a.Lots)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Action)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.ActionResponses)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Organization)
                     .Include(a => a.Lots)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Responses)
                     .ThenInclude(a => a.Organization)
                     .First(a => a.Id == eventId);
}
```

This throws an error:

> Sequence contains no elements

Fun part is, when I copy & pasted this code inside controller, it found the needed record. I passed this record's id to the method, but it thrown the same exception:

```
[HttpGet("testPublish")]
public IActionResult TestPublish()
{
    Guid eventId = Guid.Parse("5522936D-70B1-4B75-3B83-08D97DC382B7");
    var events = _dbContext.Events.ToList();
    var e = events.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == eventId);
    var test = _dbContext.Events
                .Include(a => a.Lots).ThenInclude(a => a.Action).ThenInclude(a=>a.ActionStatus)
                .Include(a => a.Lots).ThenInclude(a => a.Action).ThenInclude(a=>a.ActionResponses).ThenInclude(a=>a.ActionResponseItems).ThenInclude(a=>a.Items)
                .Include(a => a.Lots).ThenInclude(a => a.Action).ThenInclude(a => a.ActionResponses).ThenInclude(a=>a.Organization)
                .Include(a=>a.Lots).ThenInclude(a=>a.Responses).ThenInclude(a=>a.Organization)
                .First(a => a.Id == eventId);

    _service.FinishEvent(test.Id);

    return Ok();
}
```

Basically, the code is working from controller, but not from the repo, and I don't know what could cause this.

Edit 1. Added DbContext intialization, DI and hosted services.

Startup.cs:

```
           public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ActionDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
        }
```

DI is standard, not sure if needed, but anyway:

```
public class MyAwesomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly INotificationService _service;
        private readonly ActionDbContext _dbContext;
        public MyAwesomeController(INotificationService service, ActionDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _service = service;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
    }
```

Since I can't inject `DbContext` into hosted service, I do like this:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ActionDbContext>();
//some logic
            }
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ActionDbContext>();
                        var actions = dbContext.Actions.ToList();
                        var handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStateActionHandler>();
                        foreach (var a in actions)
                        {
                            //some more logic
                        }
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like it's something in `FinishEvent` which you haven't given us.

Comment: I checked FinishEvent, eventId is correct there, and call to repository method is on the first line:
``public void FinishEvent(Guid eventId)


        {

            var e = _eventRepository.GetEventForFinishNotification(eventId);``

Comment: @Jamil Are the controller and repository looking at the same `DbContext` instance, pointing to the same database?

Comment: @RichardDeeming I'm sure that I have only one connection string specified, so yes, they are looking at the same database. However, I'm not sure about the instance, I initialize context in startup and use DI, but I also have hosted services that use context inside a scope. Should I update question with initialization/di/scope usage code?

Comment: @Jamil Adding the init/di code would probably be helpful. I assume you've configured the `DbContext` as a `Scoped` service, rather than creating a single instance?

Comment: @RichardDeeming yes. I updated the question with init/di/hosted code

Comment: @Jamil Your "hosted service" code makes me suspect there's something more complicated going on than the initial description suggests. Are you running some sort of message queue to process the `FinishEvent` request in the background?

Comment: Are you sure the record is persisted to the database (by calling `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @Tvde1 yes, I'm sure

Comment: @RichardDeeming I just noticed that hosted services throw ``There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection``, so probably, that's the issue. Thanks. Is there a way to use ``DbContext`` in hosted services?

Comment: @Jamil The [MS docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task-1) seems to be similar to yours. They create a separate scoped service class to do the actual work, and use `BeginScope` / `GetRequiredService` to resolve an instance of that service.

Comment: Yes, but no ``DbContext`` example, will try to find some examples. Thanks

Comment: return _dbContext.Events (where e.eventId== eventId Include(a => a.Lots)...